# Some error with .htaccess dont know whats wrong

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey guys i dont know what i'm doing wrong here.

www.example.com/data/stuff1/stuff2/stuff3

to

www.example.com/anything.php?par1=data&&par2=stuff1/stuff2/stuff3

And this is what i had written. Please help me out figure out my mistake.
Ps. I'm very new to .htaccess.

Thanks!

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !www\.a3k\.in
 RewriteRule     /([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /anything.php?api=$1&&data=$2    [NC,L]
```

Comment: I do some retag, as you should mention the "main" context, the Apache Web Server and the mod_rewrite, instead of ".htaccess". I think the question revolve around that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in a `RewriteRule` does not contain a preceding slash, and because you didn't add a `^` to mark the beginning of the path, this may have caused a wrong behavior. So try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ anything.php?api=$1&data=$2 [NC,L]
```

Additionally I added a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to make sure that URLs of actually existing files won't be rewritten.

Comment: Thanks a lot floern! What i want to still understand as to what was going wrong? was the www.example.com also getting rewritten?